# Tier 15 with Memory of Felwinter?

Tags: destiny

I was wondering if it was possible to get Tier 15 with Memory of Felwinter (Intellect is pointless with this artifact, but just as a fun thing to see all of the stats maxed out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. Here's a screenshot from someone who managed to get "tier 15" about a month ago:

[image: tier 15]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  However, since Memory of Felwinter removes your Super, there is no point in having Tier 5 Intellect.

Comment: I know; I stated it in the question. However, I thought that it would be cool to see all of the bars being filled up.